# Hiding text in boot sequence - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot

Can you please tell me how to completely hide text in Ubuntu 22.04. This is what i got on /etc/default/grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I might have messed up with other commands, trying to fix the issues on my own. I don't know if can make any difference but I have installed and Nvidia graphic card gtx 1050 ti.

I apoligize in case I have breached any rules.